# unable to run pytorch CUDA extension inside docker container

Tags: python, c++, docker, pytorch

I am developing custom pytorch CUDA extension in the docker container- However it gives strange error (not related to code itself). Code was working as visual studio project locally.

```
error: identifier "atomicAdd_block" is undefined
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

my includes in cuda file

```
#include <torch/extension.h>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
#include <cooperative_groups/reduce.h>
#include <cooperative_groups/memcpy_async.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

dockerfile

```
ARG PYTORCH_IMAGE=nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.04-py3
FROM ${PYTORCH_IMAGE}
```

run arguments

```
    "runArgs": ["--init", "--gpus", "all"
        ,"--ipc", "host"
    ]
```

nvcc version displayed in container terminal

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
```

pytorch version :1.12.0
Torch.cuda.is_available() : True

I perform jit compilation
code is available in

```
https://github.com/jakubMitura14/extension-cpp/blob/master/check.py
```

file to execute check.py

Comment: Having the same issue. Could you fix your problem?

Comment: As far as I analyzed it it boils down to correct set of tool versions for example one can  run python from x64 native tools command prompt on windows 10 with cuda 11.3 installed and python 3.9 and cuda11.3 supporting pytorch, and it should work